# How to join 2 or more data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have multiples dataframes, similar to

DF1

```
Element Category              Subcategory  Subsystem    Role                             Fcount
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    phosphoribosyltransferase domain    1
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    Biotin operon repressor             1
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)      2
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    ligase (EC 6.3.4.15)                1
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)              1
E100    Cofactors, Vitamins   Pigments     Biotin       synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)              1
```

DF2

```
Element Category              Subcategory  Subsystem    Role                             Fcount
E200    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    phosphoribosyltransferase domain    1
E200    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    Biotin operon repressor             1
E200    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)      2
E200    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    toxin (EC 6.3.4.15)                 1
E200    Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)              1
```

First, all the lines that present the same string from **Category** to the **Role** columns will be considered equal; if it is different in one or more columns, then it will be considered different rows!!!!

Example1, Line 1 in DF1 and DF2

Both lines present the same pattern in **Category**, **Subcategory**, **Subsystem** and **Role** columns: **Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    phosphoribosyltransferase domain**, so it is considered equal!!!

Example 2

Those that are present in some but not all columns (as: **Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    ligase (EC 6.3.4.15)** and **Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    toxin (EC 6.3.4.15)**) add zero in those that are not present. In the case of the last row of DF1 (**Cofactors, Vitamins   Pigments     Biotin       synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)**) that has differences in the columns of **Subcategory** and  **Subsystem**, then it must be added as a different row.

The **Fcount** column will be changed to the name of the Element, and add it from the 5 to Nnumber of columns (in this case 5 to 6 column)!

The final data frame will be like:

```
Category              Subcategory  Subsystem    Role                             E100  E200
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    phosphoribosyltransferase domain    1   1
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    Biotin operon repressor             1   1
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)      2   2
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    ligase (EC 6.3.4.15)                1   0
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)              1   1
Cofactors, Vitamins   Biotin       synthesis    toxin (EC 6.3.4.15)                 0   1
Cofactors, Vitamins   Pigments     Biotin       synthase (EC 2.3.1.47)              1   0
```

Well in this case, I just used as example 2 data frames, but I have more than 20.

How could do that in R ??

Sorry if I don give any code but I have not idea how to do it !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, but I tend to use the tidyverse solution [Link to documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html), you just need to use the `by` argument.

```
df_com <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("Category", "Subcategory", "Subsystem", "Role"))
```

Then, you can just rename the Fcount.x and Fcount.y columns to E100 and E200 using `rename`.
There's also some base R and data.table solutions, but I'm less familiar with them